# c# linq to xml take one element of many

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have this code

```
List<Customer> customersList =
                (
                    from e in XDocument.Load(file).Root.Elements("cust")
                    select new Customer
                    {
                        CustomerID = (int)e.Attribute("custid"),
                        FirstName = (string)e.Attribute("fname"),
                        LastName = (string)e.Attribute("lname"),
                        ShowsNumber = (int)e.Attribute("count_noshow"),
                        VisitNumber = (int)e.Attribute("count_resos"),
                        Cancellation = (int)e.Attribute("count_cancel"),

                    }).ToList();
```

as you see, I am extracting the attributes, but I have three (sometimes four) elements of `phone` I want to extract the first element of them.

I tried this:

```
(string)e.Elements
```

but I don't know what should I do now

could you help me please?

#### XMl

```
<cust memberid="12345678" lname="Smith" fname="Bill" email="bsmith@acme.com" emailoptin="0" mailoptin="0" cnotes="Likes the corner booth." birthday="2000-04-05" ><address memberid="12345678" address1="123 Main Street" address2=" " city="Carol Stream" state="IL" zip="60188-4746" country="United States" /> 
<phone countrycodeid="1" memberid="12345678" phonenumber="4156667777" phonetype="Home"/>
<phone countrycodeid="1" memberid="12345678" phonenumber="4157778888" phonetype="Mobile"/>
<phone countrycodeid="1" memberid="12345678" phonenumber="4158889999" phonetype="Work"/>
<custcode memberid="12345678" ccode="VIP"/>
```

Comment: Could you show your XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
XElement phoneElement = doc.Element("phone");
```

doc.Element("phone") will grab the first element of "phone" in the xml file.

```
var phoneNumber = phoneElement.Attribute("phonenumber").Value.ToString();
```

Use the Attribute method to grab the value of the attribute.

Comment: but as you see in the question, there are many `phone` elements, and the value is stored in the `phonenumber `attribute

Comment: Did you mean this? `MobileNumber = (string) e.Element("phone").Attribute("phonenumber")`

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli The Element method will grab the first element in the xml file. In this case the "phone" element. I updated my answer.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Pardon let me rephrase that... The Element method will grab the first specified element in the file. So in this case I specified "phone" so it will grab the first "phone" element it sees.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it.

This assumes there will always be at least one `<phone>` with at least one `<phonenumber>` and we just want the first of each:

```
List<Customer> customersList =
            (
                from e in XDocument.Load(file).Root.Elements("cust")
                select new Customer
                {
                    CustomerID = (int)e.Attribute("custid"),
                    FirstName = (string)e.Attribute("fname"),
                    LastName = (string)e.Attribute("lname"),
                    ShowsNumber = (int)e.Attribute("count_noshow"),
                    VisitNumber = (int)e.Attribute("count_resos"),
                    Cancellation = (int)e.Attribute("count_cancel"),

                    PhoneNumer = (string)e.Descendants("phone")
                                           .First()
                                           .Select(p=>p.Attributes("phonenumber").First().Value)

                }).ToList();
```